# Data does not appear when i use a variable as parameter

Tags: javascript, php, plsql

I try to show data through the modal, When using a variable, the data does not appear in the browser .
But when i use fixed number instead variable like(327), the data appears normally ,
ps :when i print the variable it gives the same value as the number i have put as fixed (327)

```
    $x=$this->input->post('SEQ');
    $data = $this->image->PIC_News_SELECT($x); // there are no output   
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($data);


 $data = $this->image->PIC_News_SELECT(327); // the data appears normally 
 header('Content-Type: application/json');
 echo json_encode($data);
```

Comment: What has this got to do with JS?

Comment: i use it to pass the seq(327) value to modal that get data depending on it

Comment: What shows `var_dump($x)`?

Comment: 327 the same fixed number

Comment: why is this tagged as plsql ?

Comment: i use plsql to store data

Comment: Please post the plsql component.